# How to import and interact with MakeHuman models on Android?

Tags: android, iphone, graphics, opengl-es

I have recently been learning about OpenGL on Android and developed a basic human model using [MakeHuman](http://www.makehuman.org/).

Where I am stuck and somehow can't find any information on Google or the MakeHuman site is how to take models made by MakeHuman and import them into my Android app for use. To be more specific:

1. I am developing the App from scratch on Eclipse, so when I say
   "import" I just mean add it as a resource to my Android app and
   interact with it using OpenGL ES.
2. I am planning to make the model interactive, a bit like a video game, such that I can move, rotate the body
3. I also will need to change colors on different parts of the model's body.

I got to assume a model from MakeHuman can support these features, I just don't know how or see an guides...

I know this question could seem vague, but its actually specific, I am asking about:

1. How to import a model into Android
2. How to interact with that model using OpenGL ES
3. Information on pitfalls, best practices to get this done efficiently
4. Also, how to make sure the model can be used across other devises such as iOS, ThreeJS, WebGL, etc.

Comment: If there are books, web guides, or something solid out there that can help solve this, I'd be interested too!

Comment: i say use unity3d, its the easyest way i think to use models animations and the such, i use to use opengl just with android and i had to make a class to parse the .fbx,.obj or whatever so opengl can read the vertices and such, that was opengl1.0 it might have advanced to where theres built in classes

Comment: @JRowan I am okay with that. I'd rather not rely on premium software. As long as I know how to parse the .obj files and such, its all fine by me.

Comment: this http://www.apress.com/9781430230427 is the book i read it uses opengles1.0 and it only shows you how to import .obj files, the class that parses the file is tied into the whole library that the book works upto creating lesson by lesson, if you scroll down to the source code files you can get the source code and use it it you want thats all i can do for you

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is basically a game engine.  Unity3D does have the best solution, particularly if you must have cross-platform support, however I think that gets fairly expensive, unless you stick to just one platform.

A good lightweight and free solution is available in the PowerVR SDK.  Their PVRTools and PVREngine libraries can import Collada (.dae) or .pod with texture coordinates and basic animations.  I think they are adding .obj support, but I don't know if it's there yet.

http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/sdkdownloads/index.asp